# Application Command raised an exception: TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1. Trying to remove a line from a text file (PyCord)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, pycord

Im making a Discord bot using the PyCord library that is effectivly a word of the day/phrase of the day bot for a language server. One of the requests is that it has the ability to add and remove words in discord which the bot will send. I wrote the code for the commands which where working perfectly upuntil 2 days ago where it no longer functions at all despite no changes to the code. thats beside the point anyway, any help on how to get this code to work would be greatly appreciated :).

Code:

```
#The commands!
@self.slash_command(name="add_word")
async def greet(ctx, add_word: Option(str, "What word do you wish to add", required = True, default = '')):
        with open("words.txt", "a") as n:
                   n.write("\n" + add_word)
        await ctx.respond(f"Added the word: **{add_word}** to the list")

@self.slash_command(name="remove_word") 
async def greet(ctx, remove_word: Option(str, "What word do you wish to remove?", required = True, default = '')):
        with open("words.txt", 'w') as file:
                new_text_1 = str.replace(remove_word, '')
                file.write(new_text_1)
        await ctx.respond(f"Removed the word: **{remove_word}** from the list")

@self.slash_command(name="add_phrase")
async def greet(ctx, phrase_entry: Option(str, "What phrase do you wish to add", required = True, default = '')):
        with open("phrases.txt", "a") as n:
                   n.write("\n" + phrase_entry)
        await ctx.respond(f"Added the word: **{phrase_entry}** to the list")

@self.slash_command(name="remove_phrase") 
async def greet(ctx, remove_phrase: Option(str, "What phrase do you wish to remove?", required = True, default = '')):
        with open("phrases.txt", 'w') as file:
                new_text_1 = str.replace(remove_phrase, '')
                file.write(new_text_1)
        await ctx.respond(f"Removed the phrase: **{remove_phrase}** from the list")

@self.slash_command(name="add_hard_word")
async def greet(ctx, add_hard_word: Option(str, "What difficult word do you wish to add", required = True, default = '')):
        with open("hard_words.txt", "a") as n:
                   n.write("\n" + add_hard_word)
        await ctx.respond(f"Added the hard word: **{add_hard_word}** to the list")

@self.slash_command(name="remove_hard_word") 
async def greet(ctx, remove_hard_word: Option(str, "What difficult word do you wish to remove?", required = True, default = '')):
        with open("hard_words.txt", 'w') as file:
                new_text_1 = str.replace(remove_hard_word, '')
                file.write(new_text_1)
        await ctx.respond(f"Removed the hard word: **{remove_hard_word}** from the list")

@self.slash_command(name="add_hard_phrase")
async def greet(ctx, hard_phrase_entry: Option(str, "What difficult phrase do you wish to add", required = True, default = '')):
        with open("hard_phrases.txt", "a") as n:
                   n.write("\n" + hard_phrase_entry)
        await ctx.respond(f"Added the hard word: **{hard_phrase_entry}** to the list")

@self.slash_command(name="remove_hard_phrase") 
async def greet(ctx, remove_hard_phrase: Option(str, "What difficult phrase do you wish to remove?", required = True, default = '')):
        with open("hard_phrases.txt", 'w') as file:
                new_text_1 = str.replace(remove_hard_phrase, '')
                file.write(new_text_1)
        await ctx.respond(f"Removed the hard phrase: **{remove_hard_phrase}** from the li
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how it was working before. I think your issues are within the `remove` commands for removing words and phrases.

Let's take your `remove_word` command.

```py
@self.slash_command(name="remove_word") 
async def greet(ctx, remove_word: Option(str, "What word do you wish to remove?", required = True, default = '')):
    with open("words.txt", 'w') as file:
        new_text_1 = str.replace(remove_word, '')
        file.write(new_text_1)
    await ctx.respond(f"Removed the word: **{remove_word}** from the list")
```

In this, we open the text file to remove the word from. And then we, call the `str.replace` function on `str`? Huh? The [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) should be called on the string you want to replace things in - this is why it's throwing that weird error message. So, to do so, we need to actually read the lines/words in `words.txt` and then remove those occurences from the file.

That might end up looking something like this:

```py
@client.slash_command()
async def remove_word(ctx, word: str):
    word_to_remove = word.lower()
    with open("words.txt", "r+") as f:
        file_words = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0)
        for file_word in file_words:
            if file_word.strip("\n") != word_to_remove:
                f.write(file_word )
        f.truncate()
    await ctx.respond(f"Removed the word: **{word}** from the list")
```

I have simplified it a little - remove the `self` and `Option`; but you can add those back in later.

So, what we're doing:

- making the inputted word all lowercase for easy converting (I'm assuming your word list is all lowercase as well)
- opening our text file with the `r+` mode - this allows us to read and write the file without removing if it if already exists
- then we use `f.readlines()` to read every line into a list as `file_words`
- *then*, we do `f.seek(0)` to go back to the beginning of the file (as `f.readlines()` will "read" the whole file and put as at the end)
- then we iterate over our list of words from the file (not that each word will also have a newline symbol "\n")
- and then, if that word **does not** equal the word we want to remove (note how we check it minus the newline), we write it back into the file
- and then we call `f.truncate()` to remove the stuff that was in the file before
- and finally we can send our message to the user saying it was removed

Note that I didn't use replace at all - I wanted to remove the line completely rather than making it an empty line. You can of course, do some more complicated checks for word equality if you want to as well.

Hopefully this is enough to apply it in your context and update your other `remove` methods as well.

Separately, I would rename all of the function names as well to something that matches what it does - so that they're not all called `greet`. It's better practice and will make things easier as you go. That way, you don't need to specify the `name` of the command either, as it can just be the function name.

Comment: Thank you so much, that's really helped a lot :),
From your answer I have no idea how it was working before lmao.

Im quite new to python and discord bots in general so I'm still trying to figure out how this stuff works haha so thank you again for the in-depth answer :)